# PHP - JSON returning null with different objects

Tags: php, json

I have two different set of json object as follows.

```
'{
  "eventos": [
     {"Event":"QueueParams","Queue":"755","Max":"0","Strategy":"fewestcalls","Calls":"0","Holdtime":"19","TalkTime":"491","Completed":"89","Abandoned":"4","ServiceLevel":"0","ServicelevelPerf":"0.0","Weight":"0","ActionID":"4152750549"},
     {"Event":"QueueMember","Queue":"755","Name":"PJSIP/428","Max":"","Location":"PJSIP/428","StateInterface":"PJSIP/428","Membership":"dynamic","Penalty":"0","CallsTaken":"2","LastCall":"1607350581","Status":"2","Paused":"0","ActionID":"4152750549"},
  ]
}';

$response = json_decode($response);
dd($response);
```

The problem is, it returns null output.

I want to get json result displayed with different objects. What changes are needed here so that I can display output of different objects ?

Comment: If this is truly all that is in your JSON, then it's invalid. The trailing comma behind the second object in the array should be removed.

Comment: Looking at your [previous asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11896163/nikunj-v?tab=questions), if somebody answers your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON have a syntax error. Just remove the comma right after the last `{ ActionID":"4152750549"},`.

It have to be like this:

```php
'{
  "eventos": [
     {"Event":"QueueParams","Queue":"755","Max":"0","Strategy":"fewestcalls","Calls":"0","Holdtime":"19","TalkTime":"491","Completed":"89","Abandoned":"4","ServiceLevel":"0","ServicelevelPerf":"0.0","Weight":"0","ActionID":"4152750549"},
     {"Event":"QueueMember","Queue":"755","Name":"PJSIP/428","Max":"","Location":"PJSIP/428","StateInterface":"PJSIP/428","Membership":"dynamic","Penalty":"0","CallsTaken":"2","LastCall":"1607350581","Status":"2","Paused":"0","ActionID":"4152750549"}
  ]
}';
```

For any Json problem, run a `json_last_error()` right after the decode.

Answer (score 1):

For example, to show each `ActionID`;

```php
<?php
    $rawJson = '{"eventos": [{"Event":"QueueParams","Queue":"755","Max":"0","Strategy":"fewestcalls","Calls":"0","Holdtime":"19","TalkTime":"491","Completed":"89","Abandoned":"4","ServiceLevel":"0","ServicelevelPerf":"0.0","Weight":"0","ActionID":"4152750549"}, {"Event":"QueueMember","Queue":"755","Name":"PJSIP/428","Max":"","Location":"PJSIP/428","StateInterface":"PJSIP/428","Membership":"dynamic","Penalty":"0","CallsTaken":"2","LastCall":"1607350581","Status":"2","Paused":"0","ActionID":"4152750549"} ] }';
    $json = json_decode($rawJson);

    $eventos = $json->eventos;

    foreach ($eventos as $event) {
        echo $event->ActionID . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

---

**Note:** There was an trailing comma (`,`) behind the last `event` object, I've removed it to make it valid JSON.

[Try it online!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9b3cc40909a1210ba2058580fd2f8885ea70fcb)